# How do you refactor long ruby method signatures like this one

Tags: ruby, refactoring, rubocop, keyword-argument

How can I clean up this ruby method signature?

```
def card(title: nil, textured: nil, threed: true,
         borderless: false, bodyless: false, title_classes: ['card-header'])
```

The problem is that I get a linting/rubocop warning:

```
Metrics/ParameterLists: Avoid parameter lists longer than 5 parameters. [6/5]
```

The reason I have so many keyword arguments for my method is,
I made the method really flexible. It's powerful.

Comment: I honestly ignore this for keys. You could create a parameter object, but you'll still be passing those attributes to the parameter object. This cop seems much more applicable to parameters that aren't keyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a case class/data class with those attributes.

```
class CardProperties
  attr_accessor :title, :textured, :threed, :borderless, :bodyless, :title_classes
end
```

Create a new `CardProperties` and pass it to the card method:

```
card_properties = CardProperties.new
card_properties.title = ''
....

card(card_properties)
```

Comment: can you elaborate how I can integrate you solution in to my code. My method is defined in app/lib/Company/Ui.rb

Comment: this card method is a view helper. So in my erb view I don't feel comfortable instiating classes like that

Comment: OMG. At least, one might use [`OpenStruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) here instead of trying to mimic it’s functionality with a self-made class.

Comment: @mudasobwa using a custom class represents your logic (i.e. `CardProperties`) and easy to understand.

Comment: Eh? `OpenStruct.new(title: nil, ...)` does it way better with three times less amount of code.

Comment: Look up "Method Object Refactor" from Fowler's /Refactoring/ book here...

Comment: @mudasobwa it is not always about how short your code is.

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior, could you instantiate it in the controller? `@card_properties = CardProperties.new`

Comment: @Philip, did you mean to provide a link?

Comment: @iGian, note there is no Rails tag.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in theory you might use a keyword argument and [`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) to handle default values:

```
def card(**params)
  title = params.fetch(:title, nil)
  textured = params.fetch(:textured, nil)
  threed = params.fetch(:threed, true)
  borderless = params.fetch(:borderless, false)
  bodyless = params.fetch(:bodyless, false)
  title_classes = params.fetch(:title_classes, ['card-header'])
  ...
```

But my personal advice would be to just shut up rubocop with:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/ParameterLists
def card(...)
  ...
end   
# rubocop:enable Metrics/ParameterLists
```

Comment: The second one, for whole project.

Answer (score 1):

Just do what rails does

```
  # Creates a number field.
  #
  # ==== Options
  # * <tt>:min</tt> - The minimum acceptable value.
  # * <tt>:max</tt> - The maximum acceptable value.
  # * <tt>:in</tt> - A range specifying the <tt>:min</tt> and
  #   <tt>:max</tt> values.
  # * <tt>:within</tt> - Same as <tt>:in</tt>.
  # * <tt>:step</tt> - The acceptable value granularity.
  # * Otherwise accepts the same options as text_field_tag.
  #
  # ==== Examples
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity'
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', '1'
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, class: 'special_input'
  #   # => <input class="special_input" id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, min: 1
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, max: 9
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" max="9" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, in: 1...10
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="9" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, within: 1...10
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="9" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, min: 1, max: 10
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', nil, min: 1, max: 10, step: 2
  #   # => <input id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" step="2" type="number" />
  #
  #   number_field_tag 'quantity', '1', class: 'special_input', disabled: true
  #   # => <input disabled="disabled" class="special_input" id="quantity" name="quantity" type="number" value="1" />
  def number_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
    options = options.stringify_keys
    options["type"] ||= "number"
    if range = options.delete("in") || options.delete("within")
      options.update("min" => range.min, "max" => range.max)
    end
    text_field_tag(name, value, options)
  end
```